# Problems with selecting option with loading data with Ajax request with the object select option

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have performed a rest service performed with C # with ajax request in a combo box, this object shows the data of my rest service, this combo box must fill data from many cities and this shows the cities that I perform in the service, but the inconvenience is in the object combo box or select option in html5, whenever I give in the object, it loads the data and I cannot select my city that I want, reloading it, as an infinite loop when I want to select the data Annex code

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279794/problemas-en-mostrar-datos-en-combo-box-en-pantalla-con-petici%c3%b3n-ajax

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label>Ciudad</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-rel="chosen"  id="Ciudad" name="Ciudad" onclick="ValidarExisteCiudad()">
        <option/>
        <option/>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
function ValidarExisteCiudad() {
    //$("[data-rel='chosen']").chosen();
    //var ddlCiudad = $("[data-rel='chosen']");
    var ddlCiudad = $("#Ciudad");
    ddlCiudad.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">Loading.....</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "CargaCiudad",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


                ddlCiudad.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Seleccione ...</option>');
                $.each(data, function () {
                   ddlCiudad.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));

                });
                // After updated data from database you need to trigger chosen:updated.
                //$("[data-rel='chosen']").trigger("chosen:updated");
            },  
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
                existeUsuario = false;
            }
        });




}
```

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CargaCiudad()
        {
            List<Cuidad> Items = await drHelpPrueba.Cuidad.ToListAsync();
            List<SelectListItem> ciudad = new List<SelectListItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ciudad.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = Convert.ToString(Items.ToList()[i].IdCiudad),
                    Text = Items.ToList()[i].Nombre
                });
            }

            return Json(ciudad);

        }
```

ddlCiudad.append($("").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));

undefined

Answer (score 0):

my friend. Because you don't get true data from the response.

Try following this. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
function ValidarExisteCiudad() {

    var ddlCiudad = $("#Ciudad");
    ddlCiudad.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">Loading.....</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "CargaCiudad",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


                ddlCiudad.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Seleccione ...</option>');
                $.each(data, function () {
                    ddlCiudad.append($("<option>  </option>").val(this.value).html(this.text)); //Modified this line

                });
                // After updated data from database you need to trigger chosen:updated.
                //$("[data-rel='chosen']").trigger("chosen:updated");
            },  
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
                existeUsuario = false;
            }
        });




}
```